# How to present the idea of "Same Month/Same Quarter/Yearly Comparison" in a less clumsy way?

Tags: phrases

I am thinking of the title of my chart, since the concept is there but the output is a bit too clumsy, I wonder if I can get any inspiration from here:

The chart is about showing a trend of a certain kind of infection rate in hospital. The chart can be adjusted to show the bars of all "January", "February", etc... from 2007-2010, all "Quarter 1", "Quarter 2", etc... from 2007-2010, and the bar for yearly data (2007-2010).

I know the monthly and quarterly bars can be grouped together, as their all refer to the "specific month/quarter" (I wonder if "specific" is the appropriate term here) across the years, but the yearly bars is a bit different. It is put here because of technical issue, they consider yearly bars as "specific year" across the years, but year itself does not include subsets of years.

Currently I can think of "Same Month/Quarter/Year Comparison of XXX Infection", I wonder if this can properly deliver my message.

Comment: Maybe an example picture would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for comparing corresponding periods across years you use the expression [year on year](http://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=6674)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to be elegant when trying to represent multi-dimensional information in a linear sentence. I might suggest something like "Comparison of Infection Rate by Month, Quarter or Year."

However, I suspect you're doing this in Excel or a similar spreadsheet application. Have you considered including the relevant sample period in the title, so it changes dynamically to show only the word Month/Quarter/Year as appropriate? There are plenty of [tips](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=56931&page=1) online explaining how.